# Empty constructor or no constructor

Tags: c#

I think it is not mandatory to have a default constructor in a class (C#).

So, in that situation shall I have an empty constructor in the class or can I  skip it?

Is it a best practice to have an empty default constructor?

```
Class test
{
   public test()
   {

   }
        ......
}
```

or

```
Class test
{
        ......
}
```

Answer (score 96, accepted):

If the class won't be used by third parties and you don't need an overloaded constructor, don't write an empty constructor.

But...

Imagine you already shipped the product, and third parties use your class. A few months later there's a new requirement that makes you add a constructor with an argument.

Now, by doing so, the C# compiler no longer generates a default constructor. If you don't add an empty constructor explicitly, the third party code will be break.

In my opinion, you should always define empty constructors (one liner) for public classes used by third parties.

Comment: On another topic, if you want to use your .NET class in a COM program, a public no-args constructor will be required - for the same reasons as Soe Moe explained, I would explicitly put it in the class.

Comment: You could argue that your own unit tests should fail if you're going to break 3rd party clients in this way.

Comment: Sometimes simplifying your approach by habitually using a certain pattern is fine.  It's my reason for using javascript semicolons (because I don't want to remember when they're necessary vs when they're clutter).  However I think in this case I would rely on the unit tests to catch errors instead of placing empty constructors everywhere.  Personal preference I suppose.  Regardless, this answer is great as it exposes the logic for why one would prefer to explicitly add empty constructors.

Comment: Still, there's no technical need to write the default constructor when one is generated by the compiler. You use it just as a preventive measure not to forget to specify one once another constructor overload is added. When using a parameterless constructor is supposed to be a supported use case, it should be ensured by a unit test instead of polluting the code with boilerplate.

Answer (score 38):

[KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) - If your class doesn't need to do anything in the default constructor - don't define it. The compiler will generate one for you.

From the [horse's mouth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx):

> Unless the class is static, classes
>   without constructors are given a
>   public default constructor by the C#
>   compiler in order to enable class
>   instantiation.

Comment: To clarify: If your class *does* have at least one constructor that has one or more parameters, then the C# compiler will *not* create a default constructor for you. In that case, you *may* want to explicitly create a default constructor, even if it does not do anything (i.e., it is empty). (See the accepted answer and others for more.)

Answer (score 12):

`There's nothing like default constructors`. It's public parameter-less constructor in C#. C# compiler will look for constructors in a class while compiling and will add a public parameter-less constructor if no constructors are defined. So it's ok to skip defining a constructor if your class objects don't need any special operation for construction.

Secondly, if you define one constructor with parameter then compiler will not add a public parameter-less constructor because compiler will assume your objects must be constructed via the constructor you've defined. Having said that, you must explicitly define a parameter-less constructor if you have at least one parameterized constructor, if you need your objects to construct with parameteress constructor.

You can also have a private parameterless constructor as well that is instrumental in making singleton classes.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't need a parameterless constructor, don't add one with an empty body.  However, *if someone wants to serialize/deserialize objects of your class, then you'll need a parameterless constructor.*

If you define no constructors, then the compiler will automatically generate a default parameterless one for you, but it won't if you define a constructor yourself.

Incidentally, you can suppress the C# compiler's automatically generated default constructor by defining an empty, private constructor.

Comment: While serialization frameworks certainly *can* rely on an empty constructor and a settable properties, this is in no way a requirement. Newtonsoft.Json, for example, allows you to use any constructor for deserializing. You just have to annotate it with `[JsonConstructor]`.

Answer (score 4):

By default C# will add a zero parameter constructor for you. So don't add one if you don't have anything special to do there.

You will have to add any empty constructor yourself - even without code - if you have another constructor with parameters and want have to keep the parameter-less constructor alive.

Another scenario where you would want  to add an empty parameter-less constructor is if you want to change its access modifier from public to something else(private, protected or internal)

Answer (score 2):

The C# compiler will create the default constructor for you, so you should not write parameterless one, with an empty body.

Comment: Experience coders have told me that not having it has caused problems for them in the future e.g. static classes

Answer (score 2):

The only times I would include an empty parameterless constructor is if I want the constructor to be private or if I want a parameterless constructor to call another overload with null as the parameter.  BTW, in your example above you've made Test's constructor private by not specifying public.

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo()
        : this(null)
    {
    }

    public Foo(string bar)
    {
        if (bar != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(bar);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, the reason I noted it is because a private constructor can be useful for forcing users of your class to use any factory methods you may decide to include in your class.  For example my Foo class could have a public static Foo CreateFoo() factory method and no public constructors...

Answer (score 0):

Dont write an empty constructor it would be created by default