# C# Int32: m_value

Tags: c#

After reading a bit about the `Int32` struct in C#, I realized that `int` and `Int32` are synonymous. In [the source code of `Int32` struct](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,225942ed7b7a3252), there is a `internal int m_value` field.

If my knowledge is right, the value that we assign to a int variable is stored in `m_value` (Am I right?). But my doubt is how the value gets stored in `m_value` when we give `int i = 7;`.

I don't see any implicit operator either in the `Int32` struct source code so that the value could get stored in `m_value`.

Can any one help me with this?

Comment: Voted for reopen. Those are different questions.

Comment: @SonerGönül: i don't know the former proposed duplicate, but this seems to answer OP's question( which is actually: how is System.Int32 initialized when i assign an `int` variable): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449498/instantiation-and-initialization-of-value-types-vs-reference-types _"int is a built-in type. The compiler knows how to generate IL for it. The type of int is "baked into" the CIL the compiler generates for the assignment:

`.locals init ([0] int32 a)
ldc.i4.s   5
stloc.0`"_

Comment: @TimSchmelter It was [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113850/if-int32-is-just-an-alias-for-int-how-can-the-int32-class-use-an-int)

Comment: @TimSchmelter you can see it in the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34223128/revisions) - between edit 2 and 3

Comment: @TimSchmelter That was another question voted as a duplicate. And yes, the question you linked fits better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int` in C# represents the same thing as `int32` in CIL, which is a 4-byte primitive generally treated as a signed number. (Though CIL can do unsigned operations on it without a cast).

It's one of the lowest-level building blocks from which we can go on to create more complicated structures and classes.

But as such, it doesn't have any methods defined on it.

`System.Int32` meanwhile looks pretty much like a struct that wraps an `int`/`int32` and does provide some methods.

Let's consider it as that; let's think about what it would be like in a world without `int` being aliased with `System.Int32`:

In this hypothetical situation, we would only be allowed to use the methods `System.Int32` provides if we treated it as a special "boxed int" type, creating a `System.Int32` from an `int` when we needed it, and extracting the `int` back again when we needed that.

So, without aliasing to do `(3).CompareTo(2)` we would have to do:

```
new System.Int32{m_value = 3}.CompareTo(2)
```

But consider that the in-memory representation of `int` is 4 bytes and the in-memory representation of `System.Int32` is the same 4 bytes. If we didn't have a strong type-system that barred considering one type as another type we could just treat one as the other whenever we wanted.

Now, C# does not allow us to do this. E.g. we can't do:

```
public struct MyInt32
{
  private int _value;
}
/* … */
MyInt32 = 3;
```

We would need to add a cast method that would be called, or else C# will just refuse to work on it like this.

CIL though has no such rule. It can just treat one type as another layout-compatible type whenever it wants. So the IL for `(3).CompareTo(2)` is:

```
ldc.i4.3 // Push the 32-bit integer 3 on the stack.
ldc.i4.2 // Push the 32-bit integer 2 on the stack.
call instance int32 [mscorlib]System.Int32::CompareTo(int32)
```

The call at the end just assumes that the `3` is a `System.Int32` and calls it.

This breaks the rules of C# type-safety, but those rules are not CIL's rules. The C# compiler also doesn't have to follow all of the rules that it enforces.

So there's no need to put anything into `m_value`, we just say "oh those four bytes there, they're the `m_value` field of a `System.Int32`", and so it is magically done. (If you know C or C++ consider what would happen if you had two structs with equivalent members and cast a pointer to one of those types to `void*` and then back to a pointer of another. It's a bad practice and IIRC undefined rather than guaranteed, but the lower-level code is allowed to do those sort of things).

And **that** is how aliasing works; .Net languages' compilers special-case the cases where we need to call a method on a primitive to do this sort of type-coercion that C# code itself does not allow.

Likewise, it special cases the fact that a value-type cannot hold a field of its own type, and allows `System.Int32` to have an `int` field, though generally `struct S { public S value; }` would not be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

That's just how the language works, man!

In the stateent

```
int i = 7;
```

You *are* creating a variable of `Int32`. (i.e. the `int i` part). However, you are assigning it with a `7`. A `7` in C# (and in many other languages) is called a *literal*. This means that `7` is already an instance of `Int32`! It's like this:

Suppose you have a class

```
public class ClassA {
    public int i;
}
```

And an instance of `ClassA`:

```
ClassA obj = new ClassA ();
obj.i = 1;
```

And then you do this:

```
ClassA a = obj;
```

And you say, "I don't see any implicit operator in `ClassA` so that the value could get stored in `i`."

But `obj` is already a legit object! Just like `7`.

Comment: You have introduced a `new ClassA()` so it's not analogous. To be analogous it would have to be `ClassA obj = 1` **and** not have any implicit operator defined. It won't work in C#, but C# doesn't have to play by the rules C# enforces when it does aliasing.

Answer (score 0):

It's rather hard to follow what's going on when reading the source of the core framework.

"how the value gets stored in m_value when we give `int i=7;`"

Firstly, when the C# compiler sees `int`, it just pretends you said `System.Int32` instead (*).  Similarly when it sees `7`, it says "aha!  That's an integer literal.  I'll store it in a `System.Int32`".  So then it creates the variable `i` (of the right type), and initializes it with the value it created.

(*) That means that the source http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,225942ed7b7a3252
has:

```
public struct Int32 : *various bases*
{
    internal Int32 m_value;
```

... which is ever so slightly confusing (and wouldn't normally be legal).

Comment: Interfaces are not bases.