# What benefits do empty constructors provide in C#?

Tags: c#, constructor, default-constructor

I came to the existing project in C#. I can see that several classes have empty parameter-less constructors. Either public ones, or internal ones. The classes themselves are also public or internal. I can see neither other constructors in there, nor inheritance. I wonder what benefit this can have.

I expected that if there is absolutely no constructor, then C# compiler always creates one parameter-less empty constructor. So my question is: Is the current code (in above mentioned conditions) anyhow different than if there were no constructors? I think the only special case is internal constructor in a public class. Am I missing something more?

Comment: By empty, you mean there is nothing in it... like no code... just a declaration?

Comment: Can you give a specific example from your code, just to be sure we don't miss some nuance you feel is unimportant? It sounds to me as you're not missing anything though and then I would tend to agree, there is no point in having the constructor.

Comment: There is this potential duplicate which provides one reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963742/empty-constructor-or-no-constructor

Comment: The privacy accessor is important. The default parameterless constructor the compiler will add for you will be public, if you add an internal/private one you're in fact preventing construction from the outside. This might be important. But a public parameterless constructor, with no code, is not.

Comment: The last paragraph in the linked answer is bad advice, pure and simple. Don't add a parameterless constructor unless it is OK to construct the type using no parameters. API design is much much more complex than that.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen in last paragraph OP means (I suppose) to always add empty constructor _instead of_ relying on compiler to do that (in described circumstances). Of course if empty constructor doesn't make sense - then you should define another one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

well, "or internal ones" is a significant change; the default constructor would be public.

However, usually the reasons I see this is so that if somebody adds a specific constructor later, it doesn't represent a breaking change. Constructors are unusual in that adding a custom constructor can suddenly break things because it might *remove* the default constructor; this has consequences - including things that don't show until runtime (deserialization, for example), or until a downstream consumer of a library complains that you've broken the API.

Likewise, if the type is ever used in reflection (perhaps as a plugin): `Activator.CreateInstance` usage won't show errors due to a removed parameterless constructor until runtime.

Whether you *actually* need to do this is largely a matter of opinion, of course.

Comment: I agree, and I'd definitely lean towards not future-prepping the constructors.  Adding a constructor later will cause compiler errors (*usually*), which it should, and that decision should really be made then.  YAGNI stuff.

Comment: You won't get compiler errors from deserialization, which is what Marc is saying.

Comment: @Jonesopolis in "application" code, I'd agree with you; if it is a library that is going to be published and consumed by other people, then I'd probably argue that adding the explicit but pointless-looking constructor is *incredibly* valuable. Also, it if is a type used in serialization. You won't get compiler errors for serialization, or for places where **your code** isn't the consumer of the constructor.

Comment: I'm with you on that @MarcGravell

Comment: Not all de/serialisers require an empty constructor. Usually only DTO/POCO should be serialised anyway, where inherently there is a default empty constructor that will mitigate braking changes to any downstream de/serialisers. But as we know, that is in an ideal world which is not always the case. Seems like somebody is over zealous here due to being burnt by this before. Maybe it is not a matter of opinion though but a matter of what convention and framework you are using. If somebody is cowboying code left right and centre then life gets difficult

Comment: @ppumkin other way around: I work extensively in serialization, and I know how many times I've seen *other people* get badly burned by this.  I don't think I've ever personally been burned by it, precisely because I know all the gory details :) And if you think most people use clean DTO models: you'd be very wrong.

Comment: @marc I know ProtBuf-net requires empty constructor but it also requires attributes which causes controversy on its own for people looking for a new serialiser. It is a freaking awesome serialiser! and I use it allot but if a "entity/company" with Rich Model Development approach adds your attributes on classes with business logic.. or expects other serialiser to magically work out which constructor to use ... you know the pain they are going to go through after release. Mostly it is the reluctance to put in a bit of extra work and create specific POCO just for the job that needs to be done.

Comment: @ppumkin protobuf-net requires neither an empty constructor nor attributes, just sayin'... (you can tell it to skip the constructor, and everything can be configured at runtime if needed)

Comment: Heheh - `[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor=true)] ` - Yes sorry, if we do not need versioning we can skip the use of property index attributes. (not everybody knows that)

Comment: @ppumkin I was also talking about the `RuntimeTypeModel` API, which allows full configuration at runtime, there's no conflict with versioning here

Answer (score 2):

Internal constructors can be useful if you want to prevent instances of the class to be instantiated outside of the assembly. It's also a requirement to have a public/empty constructor to be used with the generic constraint where T : new () see, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters